# How do I add a class without having it get rid of the others?

Tags: javascript, jquery, class, addition

I have the following code set up in my footer which adds a class of 'day' during the time specified.

```
function setTimeStyles() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if(currentTime > 5 && currentTime < 17) {
    document.body.className = 'day';
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeStyles();
});
```

The problem is when the class gets added, it gets rid of the other classes already in place. For example, without the 'day' class added, my body tag would be:

```
<body class="home">
```

But when the 'day' class is added, my body tag turns into:

```
<body class="day">
```

I'd like it so that the 'day' class gets added to what's already there like this:

```
<body class="home day">
```

How can I go about doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In jQuery you can do

```
$("body").addClass("day");
```

Comment: Can I just use that code to replace document.body.className = 'day' or do I need to change anything else?

Comment: Yes, replace `document.body.className = day` with this. This is a lot easier than manually setting the `className` property, especially if you also want to be able to remove individual classes.

Comment: Do you mean like this? function setTimeStyles() {
    var currentTime = new Date().getHours();
    if(currentTime > 5 && currentTime < 17) {
    $(document).addClass("day");
    }
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    setTimeStyles();
});

Comment: Yes, that looks right. But don't take my word for it; test it!

Comment: should be $('body').addClass('day');

Comment: Thanks Andy, that works. I suppose I'll use this solution rather than manually setting the className property. Thank you Cameron and Andy.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried replacing

```
document.body.className = 'day';
```

with

```
document.body.className = document.body.className + ' day';
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how jquery adds a class,
but you may want to be sure it is added (or moved) to the **end** of any existing list,
giving it precedence in any collisions.

```
function addClass(node, cname){
 var C= node.className.split(/\s+/), L= C.length;
 while(L){
  if(C[--L]=== cname) delete C[L];
 }
 C.push(cname);
 node.className= C.join(' ').replace(/ {2,}/g,' ');
}
```