# How to add two classes to an existing class with jquery?

Tags: jquery

I have this element:

```
<div class="btn-group"></div>
```

And I have an click event in jquery and I have selected above div and now after selecting the element I want to add two classes named `dropdown` and `open` to its btn-group class.

It means I want to have this:

```
<div class="btn-group dropdown open"></div>
```

If the element already contains the `btn-group` class.

How can I do that?

Comment: Just copy your question, paste it into Google's search bar, hit enter and there it is: The first result is yours.

Comment: Dear friends:All your answers and advices were right and I knew it but all of them will wok when you dont have a class in your element.You can test it.I want to add the classes to the existing class as I said in my question.

Comment: would it solve my problem?

Comment: @Zenith Note that my element has a class right now.I just want to add two more classes to its existing one.the following answers are in the case that the element is free of any classes.they dont work in this case.

Comment: *".the following answers are in the case that the element is free of any classes"*. I think you haven't tried the others properly. `$('.btn-group')` will only select elements which have the class `btn-group`. While the answer you selected works, it is by far the most convoluted (*before it was edited*). Arun already [provided the correct answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17025223/218196).

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I add a class without having it get rid of the others?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660590/how-do-i-add-a-class-without-having-it-get-rid-of-the-others)

Answer (score 12):

Try

```
$('.btn-group').addClass('dropdown open')
```

Comment: How should we do it when we multiple .btn-group class?

Answer (score 3):

Getting the class after clicking on btn-group

```
$('.btn-group').on('click', function(){
    $(this).addClass('dropdown open');
})
```

Answer (score 2):

try this

```
$('.btn-group').addClass('dropdown');
$('.btn-group').addClass('open');
```