# Select2 how to add css style to input box after selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-select2

I am trying to add a css style to the select2 box when the user selected a value. But I cant find how to do so. I can change and add to the css file but then it will have this even when the placeholder is shown and no selection is done. When i add a class to the html it doesnt add the changes i need it to be done.

I need the following CSS aplied when a value is selected, so when the placeholder is replaced with the value of the selected value so when the allowClear event is triggerd. Is this posible? I cant find it anywhere and I am a bit new to all this, so sorry for the dumb question (english is not my main language..)

```
border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3 !important;
```

I use the folowing script:

php/html

```
<select id="filteruser" class="select_test">
   <?php while ($row33 = $result33->fetch_assoc()) { ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $row33['user']; ?>"><?php echo $row33['name']; ?></option>
    <?php } $stmt33->close();?>
    
    </select>
```

The select jquery

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
$("#filteruser").select2( {
    placeholder: "Filter user",
    allowClear: true
    } );
$('#filteruser').val('<?php echo $_SESSION['user']; ?>'); // Select the option with a value of 'the current filter'
$('#filteruser').trigger('change'); // Notify any JS components that the value changed

} );
</script>
```

EDIT: HTML output console:

```
 <select id="filteruser" tabindex="-1" class="select2-hidden-accessible" aria-hidden="true">
            <option></option> 
        <option value="123">name3</option>
            <option></option> 
        <option value="124">name4</option>
            <option></option> 
        <option value="125">name5</option>
            <option></option> 
      
        
    </select><span class="select2 select2-container select2-container--default select2-container--below select2-container--open select2-container--focus" dir="ltr" style="width: 51px;"><span class="selection"><span class="select2-selection select2-selection--single" role="combobox" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="true" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="select2-filteruser-container" aria-owns="select2-filteruser-results" aria-activedescendant="select2-filteruser-result-cx2p-123296"><span class="select2-selection__rendered" id="select2-filteruser-container"><span class="select2-selection__placeholder">Filter user</span></span><span class="select2-selection__arrow" role="presentation"><b role="presentation"></b></span></span></span><span class="dropdown-wrapper" aria-hidden="true"></span></span>
```

Comment: please provide your full code into snippet

Comment: Thanks for responding. Havent done that and i dont know how to do that at this point. I will research how to do so.

Comment: which are your select2 version ?

Answer (score 1):

You must to provide in the options: selectionCssClass:

```
$('#filteruser').select2({
      selectionCssClass: 'my-class-section'
    });
```

And the CSS:

```
.my-class-section{
  border-bottom: 1px solid #b3b3b3 !important;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! It is not working for the select2 box :(

Comment: @Martin15789 show me the HTML DOMs what are created after running this code
$("#filteruser").select2( {
    placeholder: "Filter user",
    allowClear: true
    } );

Comment: thank you for responding. Havent been able to react earlyer. I added the html response from the console to the question. I am thinking I need to use jquery to add a class to the part that is not hidden and store my CSS styles in that class so it will theme the select2. But I have not yet a idea how to pull that off.

Comment: @Martin15789 I updated my answer, take a look

Comment: Thanks. But it is not effecting the selectbox either :(

Answer (score 0):

Use JavaScript event `oninput` so an input is done a function will run like in below snippet

```js
function demofunc() {
  document.getElementById("demo").style.borderBottom = "1px solid #b3b3b3"
}
```

```css
select {
  outline: none;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<select oninput="demofunc()" id="demo">
  <option value="0">Select car:</option>
  <option value="1">Audi</option>
  <option value="2">BMW</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion ! It is not working for the select2 box :( –

Comment: I think it is not working because the default select is hidden by the select2 jquery script. So the oninput is not called.

Comment: can you provide a runnable snippet like I have provide one

Answer (score 0):

After some searching I came up with the folowing solution. I use jquery to find the existing class and add a class to that existing one. This way I can add styles to that class and style the selectbox.

```
$('.select2').addClass('someclass')
```

Found the answer here:

[How to add two classes to an existing class with jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17025199/how-to-add-two-classes-to-an-existing-class-with-jquery/17025257)

Thanks for all the help guys !